# Scala stop words

Tags: scala, text, csv, stop-words

I would like to remove the following occurences from my tweet data:

**anything with an @ (e.g. @nike)**

**anything starting with ://**

Within my scala script I have stopwords, but they must match exactly the output. Is there a way to add a stopword such as @* or ://* which would account for all the possibilities of words I want to remove?

```
val source = CSVFile("output.csv")

val tokenizer = {
SimpleEnglishTokenizer() ~>            // tokenize on space and punctuation
WordsAndNumbersOnlyFilter() ~>         // ignore non-words and non-numbers
CaseFolder() ~>                        // lowercase everything
MinimumLengthFilter(3)                 // take terms with >=3 characters 
}

val text = {
source ~>                              // read from the source file
Column(1) ~>                           // select column containing text
TokenizeWith(tokenizer) ~>             // tokenize with tokenizer above
TermCounter() ~>                       // collect counts (needed below)
TermMinimumDocumentCountFilter(30) ~>   // filter terms in <4 docs
TermStopListFilter(List("a", "and", "I", "but", "what")) ~> // stopword list
TermDynamicStopListFilter(10) ~>       // filter out 30 most common terms  
DocumentMinimumLengthFilter(5)         // take only docs with >=5 terms 
}
```

The Tokenizer doesn't seem to pick up on these non-letter characters. However it filters out # without problem.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: also look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964449/remove-standard-english-language-stop-words-in-stanford-topic-modeling-toolbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still missing many details here, since I never worked with stanford-nlp, but here's what I can make out.

I found some source code [from a forked scalanlp repository](https://github.com/dramage/scalanlp-core/blob/master/data/src/main/scala/scalanlp/stage/text/TermFilters.scala) that defines the `TermStopListFilter` as

```
/**
 * Filters out terms from the given list.
 * 
 * @author dramage
 */
case class TermStopListFilter[ID:Manifest](stops : List[String])
extends Stage[LazyIterable[Item[ID,Iterable[String]]],LazyIterable[Item[ID,Iterable[String]]]] {
  override def apply(parcel : Parcel[LazyIterable[Item[ID,Iterable[String]]]]) : Parcel[LazyIterable[Item[ID,Iterable[String]]]] = {
    val newMeta = {
      if (parcel.meta.contains[TermCounts]) {
        parcel.meta + parcel.meta[TermCounts].filterIndex(term => !stops.contains(term)) + TermStopList(stops)
      } else {
        parcel.meta + this;
      }
    }

    Parcel(parcel.history + this, newMeta,
      parcel.data.map((doc : Item[ID,Iterable[String]]) => (doc.map(_.filter(term => !stops.contains(term))))));
  }

  override def toString =
    "TermStopListFilter("+stops+")";
}
```

In the code I see that

```
if (parcel.meta.contains[TermCounts]) {
  parcel.meta + 
  parcel.meta[TermCounts].filterIndex(term => !stops.contains(term)) +
  TermStopList(stops)
}
```

It looks like the `TermCounts` object obtained from the `meta` data filters its contained terms by matching the term with the `stops` elements, using `contains`.

To filter with a more general expression it should suffice to implement a new version of the `TermStopListFilter` which uses a regular expression, for example

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex

/**
 * Filters out terms that matches the supplied regular expression.
 */
case class TermStopListFilter[ID:Manifest](regex: String)
extends Stage[LazyIterable[Item[ID,Iterable[String]]],LazyIterable[Item[ID,Iterable[String]]]] {
  override def apply(parcel : Parcel[LazyIterable[Item[ID,Iterable[String]]]]) : Parcel[LazyIterable[Item[ID,Iterable[String]]]] = {

    //extract the pattern from the regular expression string
    val pat = regex.r.pattern

    val newMeta = {
      if (parcel.meta.contains[TermCounts]) {
        parcel.meta + parcel.meta[TermCounts].filterIndex(term => pat.matcher(term).matches) // something should be added here??
      } else {
        parcel.meta + this; // is this still correct?
      }
    }

    Parcel(parcel.history + this, newMeta,
      parcel.data.map((doc : Item[ID,Iterable[String]]) => (doc.map(_.filter(term => pat.matcher(term).matches)))));
  }

  override def toString =
    "TermStopListFilter("+regex+")";
}
```